# site design: hijacked into the bounty section

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

I was in a normal (no bounty) question, clicked through to a *related* [general question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12637/a-ranger-build-that-is-close-to-tier-3-classes?rq=1), and clicked on the optimization tag to see other questions with the same tag.
Instead of a list of questions, I arrived to the empty Featured part:

> https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization
>   You are on the Featured tab.

The link looks exactly the same for featured and non-featured filter, this is part of the problem.

This is not the first time I got into Featured without wanting to, and it is quite difficoult to get out. I am not an expert in User Interaction design, but I think clicking on a tag should get me out of the *featured* context, and show me every question with that tag, with and without a bounty.

The interesting thing is stackoverflow.com works like this, but superuser.com works the way I would prefer. Both use the same stackexchange engine, so I assume this behavior is controlled by a flag in the settings.

**Long story short; could we please change it so that clicking on tags of featured questions show *all* questions with that tag, with or without a bounty?**

Stackoverflow.com has nearly 400 featured questions at the moment, it makes sense to be able to filter them with tags.
If I recall correctly, we had 3 at a time at its peak, 0 at the moment.

Comment: Would it be possible to copy the URL from your browser bar when you're looking at that view? I tried to construct one that would show me the [optimization] tag with the Featured tab active (which would be an empty page right now, yeah), and I can't figure out how it's possible to visit such a page. The URL of that view might be helpful. (I have had no success reproducing the behaviour just using the UI.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: You first need to find a tag that _has_ at least one featured question (of which there seem to be none on rpg.SE right now; you could try it on SO or maybe award a bounty yourself ;-)) and click on the "featured" tab there. Once you do that, the SE software remembers your tab choice, so if you click a non-tab-specific tag link, it'll take you to the "featured" tab even if it's empty. I'm pretty sure this has been reported on MSO before.

Comment: Ps. I see the exact same behavior on SuperUser too.  Test case: [click here](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux?sort=featured), then [click here](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mediawiki).

Comment: Ah, here it is: [Clicking on tags broken?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78989) (and its many duplicates).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: I meant to include the link, just forgot. Now it is in the question.

Comment: Now it is working fine, thanks.

Comment: And it is back to kidnap mode again.

Answer (score 3):

The current site behavior is that when you switch tabs when browsing tags, the site will remember which tab you were last on amongst *newest*, *frequent*, *votes*, etc.  The assumption is that that is your preferred navigation style and so rather than have you switch over each time, it'll just remember.

This causes issue, as has been reported several times in the past, when the *featured* tab is the one that was last used - it will remember that tab even though the majority of tags will not actually have featured questions. To a technical point, your browsing is not being hijacked but is in fact the system doing its best to *not* hijack your session and thus leaving all your browsing habits as you last left them.

The ideal goal is that we shouldn't tamper with the user's view preferences when they're browsing. Doing it specifically when the user is on a featured question and clicks any tag, we shouldn't force them onto any tab if they aren't wanting to be on other tabs. For this reason, I have for now marked this request as declined.

---

There's thought that maybe it could be nice that if you are currently defaulting to the *featured* tab and navigate to a tag that has no such questions (regardless of how you got there), that it should instead force you to, say, *newest*. That would be less consistent with the rest of the navigation, but it would be less confusing. It's something to think about as an alternative solution.